# Output content-type and other headrs in a REST Extension GET written in XQuery

Tags: rest, marklogic

I put a question about this but I associate it with a filter document problem.
It isn't, I simplify the sample to maximum and I have always the same content-type and more.
The result is always the same, no new headers fields and generic content-type

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace he.test = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/he.test";

declare function he.test:get($context as map:map,$params as map:map) as document-node() {
    let $doc := doc('/LS/MEDIA/test')
    let $_ := map:put($context, "output-type",'image/jpeg')
    let $_ := map:put($context,"ouput-headers",("Marc","value1","marc2","value2"))
    let $_ := map:put($context, "content-type",'image/jpeg')
return
$doc
};
```

this query file is deploy with ml-gradle.

Comment: What version of the server? How are You testing the REST extension?

Comment: I test with PostMan and it's the 10.0-8.3 version

Comment: I test it on version : 11.0.3, and it's the same

Comment: the result with a curl :

> GET /LATEST/resources/he.test HTTP/1.1
> Host: 212.114.16.243:8175
> Authorization: Basic bWFyYzptYXJj
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: MarkLogic
< Content-Type: application/x-unknown-content-type
< Content-Length: 37041
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior; the Content-Type header is always set based on the type of a document. For a binary document, I always get "application/octet-stream". Is your "/LS/MEDIA/test" document a JSON document, or is it actually an image? I'll do a little further research to determine if this is in fact a bug.

Comment: it's a jpeg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rjrudin is right, the correct key is `output-types` (plural.)  Note you have a typo in `output-headers` (first `t` missing.)  If you create the following service (using DHF, put it in `/src/main/ml-modules/services/xxx.xqy`):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace xxx = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/xxx";

declare function xxx:get($context as map:map, $params as map:map) as document-node()
{
    map:put($context, 'output-types',   'text/xxx'),
    map:put($context, 'output-headers', ('X-Foo', 'bar')),
    document { binary { xs:hexBinary('3432') } }
};
```

Deploy it (e.g. `./gradlew mlDeployApp`) and then go to http://localhost:8011/v1/resources/xxx.  You get the following answer (note that "42" is just interpreting both octets 0x34 and 0x32 as ASCII text):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/xxx
X-Foo: bar
Server: MarkLogic
Content-Length: 2
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

42
```

Comment: thank you Florent, I do a typo error when I test it!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a documentation bug in https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_10828 - the key should be "output-types" instead of "output-type". I tested a JS extension, and `content.outputTypes` works there, which it what made me think that the map key name in XQuery is probably "output-types" instead of "output-type".

Comment: I test with output-types :     let $_ := map:put($context, "output-types",'image/jpeg')
 
And it's the same answer :(

Comment: I test the functions : xdmp:set-response-content-type("image/jpeg") and I have the same result